# Smarty3 you say?

Tags: smarty3

Switched it on with Drupal 10.2.2 and CiviCRM 5.69.2. being an obedient kid.
Got some deprecations so far.

> 

```
Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler::$loadFilter is deprecated in Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler->__set() (line 182 of /var/www/html/dev.drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_extension_handler.php).
Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler::$loadPlugin is deprecated in Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler->__set() (line 182 of /var/www/html/dev.drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_extension_handler.php).
Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler::$registerResource is deprecated in Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler->__set() (line 182 of /var/www/html/dev.drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_extension_handler.php).
Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler::$getTemplateVars is deprecated in Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler->__set() (line 182 of /var/www/html/dev.drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_extension_handler.php).
Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler::$loadFilter is deprecated in Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler->__set() (line 182 of /var/www/html/dev.drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_extension_handler.php).
Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler::$loadPlugin is deprecated in Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler->__set() (line 182 of /var/www/html/dev.drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_extension_handler.php).
Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler::$registerResource is deprecated in Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler->__set() (line 182 of /var/www/html/dev.drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_extension_handler.php).
Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler::$getTemplateVars is deprecated in Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler->__set() (line 182 of /var/www/html/dev.drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_extension_handler.php).
Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property Smarty_Internal_Template::$compiled is deprecated in Smarty_Internal_Template->__set() (line 719 of /var/www/html/dev.drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php).
Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property Smarty_Internal_Template::$compiler is deprecated in Smarty_Internal_Template->__set() (line 719 of /var/www/html/dev.drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php).
Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler::$_codeFrame is deprecated in Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler->__set() (line 182 of /var/www/html/dev.drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_extension_handler.php).
Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler::$_filterHandler is deprecated in Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler->__set() (line 182 of /var/www/html/dev.drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_extension_handler.php).
Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler::$getLiterals is deprecated in Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler->__set() (line 182 of /var/www/html/dev.drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_extension_handler.php).
Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler::$addLiterals is deprecated in Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler->__set() (line 182 of /var/www/html/dev.drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_extension_handler.php).
Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler::$setLiterals is deprecated in Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler->__set() (line 182 of /var/www/html/dev.drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_extension_handler.php).
Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler::$getTemplateVars is deprecated in Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler->__set() (line 182 of /var/www/html/dev.drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_extension_handler.php).
Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler::$_writeFile is deprecated in Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler->__set() (line 182 of /var/www/html/dev.drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_extension_handler.php).
Deprecated function: Creation of dynamic property Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler::$clearAssign is deprecated in Smarty_Internal_Extension_Handler->__set() (line 182 of /var/www/html/dev.drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_extension_handler.php).
```

Comment: I guess you're on php 8.2. Smarty3 support still needs some work and extensions also will need time to catch up since they need to run `civix upgrade`.